# Saving multiline strings that contain variables, into a file with PHP and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, fwrite

I'm trying to save a multiline string, something like this in **plain text**:

```
define host {
        use                     template;
        host_name               $host_name;
        address                 46.224.2.220;
        contacts                $email;
}
```

**but variables e.g. $host_name and $email must be replaced with their values. s**

I couldn't figure this out. any way to achieve this?

Comment: Regular expression replacement preg_replace() - if you have tried that, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Thank you, actually I don't know how to keep that spacing and the shape similar to how it is displayed above.

Comment: I don't see why preg_/str_replace would change that - assuming you read it in right - which is a different matter that you didn't ask about, nor am I sure about the answer.

Comment: I think I did something wrong and your right. I'll try again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$plain_text = "define host {
        use                     template;
        host_name               $host_name;
        address                 46.224.2.220;
        contacts                $email;
}";


$find = array("$host_name", "$email");
$replace = array($host_name, $email);

$new_plain_text = str_replace($find, $replace, $plain_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$variables` are expanded when the string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc syntax ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)). So you can simply do:

```
$host_name = 'foo';
$email = 'bar';

$plain_text = "define host {
        use                     template;
        host_name               $host_name;
        address                 46.224.2.220;
        contacts                $email;
}";
```

However, the variables have to be defined before the string expression. If they're not, you can use the `str_replace()` method explained in other answers.